# При попытке записи сообщения пользователя в файл, записываются нечитабельные символы

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, запись

У меня возникла проблема с vk_api , а точнее с записью сообщения пользователя в файл. При выводе сообщения на экран - выводится читабельный текст, однако в файле уже не текст, а непонятные на первый взгляд шифры.
Хотелось бы узнать причину и решение данной проблемы, возможно стоит изменить код или использовать доп. pip.

```
answer = event.text # event.text - сообщение пользователя или же любой 'текст'
    w = (answer)
    f = open('words.txt') # Простой пустой файл, который в будущем будет наполнен этой командой
    qwe = f.read()
    f.close()
    begin = "#START#\n"
    end = "#END#"
    h = open('words.txt', 'r')
    virus = False
    if w not in qwe and w != '5A2035GOF74D':
        for line in h:
            virus_code=''
            virus = True
            with open('words.txt', 'r') as file:
                for line in file:
                    if begin in line:
                        pass
                    elif end in line:
                        break
                    elif '\n' not in line:
                        virus_code+=line+'\n'
                    elif '\n' in line: 
                        virus_code+=line
                with open('words.txt', 'w') as file:
                    file.write(begin + answer + '\n' + virus_code + end)
                break
    if virus == False:
        with open('words.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(begin + answer + '\n' + end)
```

В файле записываются не слова,а непонятные шифры Вконтакте

[image: Полученный текст, вместо читабельного]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте "Выключить-включить" ваше оборудование.
Если не помогло, то

```
if (переменная) != str: # Если переменная не строка
    (переменная) = str(переменная) # Превратить переменную в строку
    print("Байты прорываются!")" # Мы увидим данное сообщение, если переменная не была строкой
print(type(answer)) # Мы узнаем тип строки
```

если тип str, то всё хорошо.

Если не помогает, то попробуйте настроить текстовый редактор в котором происходит запись, возможно он давно не обновлялся или масса других причин несовместимости.
Если же и это не помогает, испробуйте заменить тип записи скрипта, изменяйте до желаемого результата.
В крайнем случае можно очистить сообщение от лишних символов, с помощью тех же функции типа:

```
list = "Dar slova ? eto prekrasno!" # Нужное на замену
symbols = ("!", "?") # Что заменяем
needs = ("Q", "W") # На что заменяем
for symbol in symbols: # Для каждого "" в symbols
    for need in needs: # Для каждого "" в needs
        if symbol in list: # Если symbol из symbols есть в list
            list.replace(symbol,need[symbols.index(symbol)]) # Заменяем в строке ненужное на нужное
print (type(list)) # Получим тип list`а
print (list) # Получим обработанную строку
```

Если будут дополнительные и индивидуальные вопросы, то с радостью дополню свой ответ.

Comment: Я вам тоже самое сказал приведите к типу str) и при сохранении байтов в файл нужно явно указывать кодировку

Answer (score 0):

*Записываются байты*

```
In [14]: data = b"""\xd2\xfb \xea\xf2\xee?""".decode("cp1251")
Out[15]: 'Ты кто?'
```

*Это нижняя строчка в ваше крякозябре так расшифровывается*

**1** *Проверьте тип answer = event.text*

```
print(type(answer))
```

*Если это байты приведите его к типу str*
*И если это байты как вы их сравниваете с str?*

Comment: **Спасибо за ответ** . Байтами происходит только запись в файл, а остальные действия осуществляются уже как со _string_ . Сам не знаю почему.

Comment: Отметьте ответ если он вам помог)

Comment: @ Александр , этот ответ мне не помог. Я сам решил проблему, сейчас приведу ответ.